# Rust mutable iterator problem - how do I fix the 'cannot infer an appropriate lifetime' error?

Tags: rust

I'm having a problem with the code below. The immutable iterator works fine, but the mutable one gives me the following error:

> cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in
> function call due to conflicting requirements.

Is it possible to somehow fix this error without using unsafe rust and sticking to the Iterator trait?

Link to the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ae0b3f4c5c7749b130fe0b0142beb9e7

Code:

```
struct Collection<T, const S: usize> {
    data: Vec<T>
}

struct CollectionIterator<'a, T, const S: usize> {
    item_index: usize,
    collection: &'a Collection<T, S>
}

struct CollectionIteratorMut<'a, T, const S: usize> {
    item_index: usize,
    collection: &'a mut Collection<T, S>
}

impl<T: Clone, const S: usize> Collection<T, S> {
    fn new(num_items: usize, default_value: T) -> Collection<T, S> {
        Collection {
            data: vec![default_value; num_items * S]
        }
    }
    fn iter(&self) -> CollectionIterator<T, S> {
        CollectionIterator {
            item_index: 0,
            collection: self
        }
    }
    fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> CollectionIterator<T, S> {
        CollectionIterator {
            item_index: 0,
            collection: self
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T, const S: usize> Iterator for CollectionIterator<'a, T, S> {
    type Item = &'a [T];
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.item_index < self.collection.data.len() {
            self.item_index += S;
            Some(&self.collection.data[self.item_index - S .. self.item_index])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T, const S: usize> Iterator for CollectionIteratorMut<'a, T, S> {
    type Item = &'a mut [T];
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.item_index < self.collection.data.len() {
            self.item_index += S;
            Some(&mut self.collection.data[self.item_index - S .. self.item_index])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut c: Collection<f64, 3> = Collection::new(5, 0.0);
    for x in c.iter_mut() {
        x[0] = 100.0;
    }
    for x in c.iter() {
        println!("{} {} {}", x[0], x[1], x[2]);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:52:23
   |
52 |             Some(&mut self.collection.data[self.item_index - S .. self.item_index])
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined on the method body at 49:13...
  --> src/main.rs:49:13
   |
49 |     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |             ^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:52:23
   |
52 |             Some(&mut self.collection.data[self.item_index - S .. self.item_index])
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 47:6...
  --> src/main.rs:47:6
   |
47 | impl<'a, T, const S: usize> Iterator for CollectionIteratorMut<'a, T, S> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/main.rs:49:46
   |
49 |       fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |  ______________________________________________^
50 | |         if self.item_index < self.collection.data.len() {
51 | |             self.item_index += S;
52 | |             Some(&mut self.collection.data[self.item_index - S .. self.item_index])
...  |
55 | |         }
56 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: expected `Iterator`
              found `Iterator`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rust
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.item_index < self.collection.data.len() {
            self.item_index += S;
            Some(&mut self.collection.data[self.item_index - S .. self.item_index])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
```

You have written code that will produce a series of mutable references to different parts of `self.collection`. But the compiler (borrow checker) does not do any analysis of the index arithmetic to determine that they are in fact non-overlapping. So, this code is rejected. In general, iterators producing mutable references into a collection cannot be written without unsafe code, because the only kind of non-overlapping references the borrow checker understands are distinct struct/tuple fields.

However, you don't need to write unsafe code to solve this particular problem, because the iterator [`std::slice::ChunksMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.ChunksMut.html), returned by [`<[T]>::chunks_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_mut), already contains the implementation you need. The non-mutable `chunks()` can replace your other iterator implementation, too.

```rust
impl<T: Clone, const S: usize> Collection<T, S> {
    fn new(num_items: usize, default_value: T) -> Collection<T, S> {
        Collection {
            data: vec![default_value; num_items * S]
        }
    }
    fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &[T]> + '_ {
        self.data.chunks(S)
    }
    fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut [T]> + '_ {
        self.data.chunks_mut(S)
    }
}
```